# Integrating JQuery in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, webjars

I am having problem of integrating JQuery into Spring boot project (New to Spring). I tried to follow the documentation but it still does not work. I am using Java/Spring + Thymeleaf. Documentation says that I have to do the following:

> 1. The WebJar needs to be a dependency of your application
> 2. The WebJar needs to be in your application's running CLASSPATH
> 3. Your container, web framework, or application needs to serve static assets from Jar files

Reference: http://www.webjars.org/documentation#springboot

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-securing-web</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- tag::security[] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end::security[] -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Then I also added resource handlers to my Config class which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class. I added the following method:

```java
        @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

Then in my HTML file I have the following lines:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        alert("JQuery works");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
    <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
    </form>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But JQuery still is not loading. It says that it is undefined. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found out the problem. Everything was correct about configuration, but I had to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` before document ready function. Can someone explain why is that so?

Comment: Okay. I found this article: http://idiallo.com/javascript/async-jquery. It looks like it has to do something with timing. Gonna dig deeper. But anyway, I got my problem solved. Case closed.

Comment: You have to load jQuery before you can use `jQuery`.