# Javascript: How do we insert a JQuery command within an external Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a separate javascript file to be used and shared through various pages. However, I ran into a problem that I absolutely cannot use any Jquery commands over there, the Spring Boot just refuses to compile it.

So, if I have a file called "content.js" and the content is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        alert("HELLO!");        
});
```

I compile and it results this:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (..\src\main\resources\static\js\content.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Is this working as intended? That I am not allowed to put a Jquery command on a separate JS file?

EDIT: So, I've been asked to show my HTML code and how I'm using the javascript. For starters, the program cannot be run because it cannot even get past the compilation phase. And as of how the it's used in the script... here's the header of the file, we'll call it 'main.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>The Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/content.js"></script>

</head>
```

I meant to locate the Javascript into a separate file on my own (content.js). But that ends up failing the compilation phase. So does this mean that if I want to use commands like the $(document).ready ... I really cannot put it in a separate Javascript file? In other words, I have to put a script within the main.html file? Therefore...

```
<body>
    (insert coding here)
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("HELLO!");        
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you run it from `node` (instead of from a browser), there is no global `document` object.

Comment: You haven't really shown how you're using the javascript in your spring-boot project, the general simple answer is that you need to load jquery cdn before the actual script. This question is related, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43057387/13927534

Comment: Is jQuery defined? Try $ = jQuery

Comment: @MissSkooter : I've edited the answer to describe the scenario better, now with the HTML sample page. The scenario I wanted is that the Javascript code that contains $(document) is located in a separate file, not in the html file. If it's actually impossible, let me know.

Comment: It doesn't matter if jquery is included in a separate file as long as jquery is loaded before the $ is used. I suspect the jquery file or the file it includes is being deferred. If you are unsure perhaps put your new script in a separate file to, and defer it.